# "Path" when using signalbuilder command in matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm trying to use signalbuilder command in matlab script to add a signal builder block in a specific existing model but every time I try I get this message

> Invalid block path

So I think the problem is with my path variable I used in the command but I can't figure out the right format for it. The model I have is Signal_Building.mdl. When path is empty (`[]`) a new model is created with the specified signal builder. The code is as follows:

```
time = 0:0.1:10;
data = {sin(time),sinh(time),(time);cos(time),cosh(time),(time).^2;tan(time),tanh(time),sqrt(time)};
groupnames = {'Triangular', 'Hyperbolic', 'Algebric'};
signames = {'Data_1','Data_2','Data_3'};
path = 'C:\Users\ME\Desktop\Matlab_Learning\Signal_Building.mdl';
block = signalbuilder(path, 'create', time, data, signames, groupnames);
```

So, I'll appreciate any one can help with the correct way defining `path`

Answer (score 0):

`path` is the path (i.e. heirarchy) *within* the model where you want the block placed.  It's *not* the path of the Simulink model within your computer's file structure.

For instance,

```
>> new_system('mymodel')
>> open_system('mymodel')
>> signalbuilder('mymodel/myblock','create',1:10,1:10);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I'd thought the model needn't be opened.